# Drupal 7, insert user_profile_form into a page

Tags: drupal-7

I tried to insert user_profile_form into a page. the code is rather simple:

global $user;
module_load_include('inc', 'user', 'user.pages'); 
print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_profile_form', $user, 'account'));

everything works fine except when uploading images, it shows:

"Warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'user_profile_form' was given in drupal_retrieve_form()"

Any ideas, thx a lot

Answer (score 3):

you need to use [form_load_include()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/form_load_include/7) instead of module_load_include to load/build a form, and you have to pass arguments inside $form_state.

the code you are looking for looks like:

```
    $form_id = 'user_profile_form';
    $form_state = array();
    //passing arguments to form.
    $form_state['build_info']['args'] = array($account, 'account');

    form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'user', 'user.pages');

    $form = drupal_build_form($form_id, $form_state);
```

Comment: To build the $account variable, use the following code
global $user;
$account = user_build_content($user);

Comment: This does work but I get: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in user_account_form() (line 1019 of /var/www/modules/user/user.module)

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the notice or warning:

> Trying to get property of non-object in user_account_form() (line 1019 of /var/www/modules/user/user.module)

Change the last two lines to:

```
<?php 
    $output_form = drupal_get_form($form_id); 
    print render($output_form); 
?>
```